# Is it possible to get the value of window.location.pathname from within a Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, web, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am trying to get the value from `window.location.pathname` (or a similar `location` read only API) inside the context of a ServiceWorker. I think one way to do that is sending that information from the page to the Service Worker via postMessage:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then( registration => {
    registration.active.postMessage({
        type: "pathname",
        value: window.location.pathname
    });
});
```

as seen in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event

However, I need that data in the `install` step of the SW lifecycle so waiting on the SW to become the active one is not ideal, and I'd rather try first to get that data earlier so I can go thru the install step with that information.

Answer (score 2):

Within the Service Worker, `self.location` is accessible via [`WorkerGlobalScope.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/location).  You could listen to requests and process those that match the same origin of your domain.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  const requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url)
  if (self.location.origin === requestUrl.origin) {
    const requestPathname = requestUrl.pathname
  }
})
```

Comment: That's close but not quite what I am hoping to get.  Origin is giving me the root of the path (for example, http://localhost:8080 when I am trying to get  http://localhost:8080/Page). This seems very particular to my case, which only makes this more difficult.

Comment: Is `requestUrl.pathname` above providing you with the `/Page` value you're seeking?